# [mongo][replicaset] Upgrade a secure replicaset, cannot upgrade secondary

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have a 3 members replicaset (1 primary, 1 arbiter, 1 secondary) running mongodb 3.2, secured with the following,  options:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /XXX/YYY.pem
    CAFile: /XXX/ZZZ.crt
    clusterFile: /XXX/YYY.pem
    allowInvalidCertificates: true

security:
   authorization: enabled
   clusterAuthMode: x509
```

All was working fine, but i need to upgrade my replicaset to 3.4.

As requested in mongodb replicaset upgrade tutorial https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/ i shutdown my secondary, reinstall binary, then restart it.

But once restart, the secondary stay in "not reachable/healty" (from rs.status() on the primary) condition.
The only logs i can see in my secondary are :

```
I ACCESS   [conn1] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetHeartbeat: "rsProd", configVersion: 34, from: "....", fromId: 5, term: 310 }
```

It seems that authentication make the replication fail by making my secondary unreachable.

Do i need to downgrade the authentication first on all the replicaset before upgrading mongodb version ?

########## EDIT

As i was unable to upgrade the configuration of this secondary, i decide to downgrade it back to the latest 3.2 version (3.2.22), i was still unable to make it work (same error).

Finally, i put it in exactly the same version as my primary: 3.2.12 and it seems to works again.

**I make it work too on version 3.2.16, 3.2.18, 3.2.19, 3.2.20
It seems that the break occurs in version 3.2.21**

What is changing in authentication mechanism between version 3.2.20 to 3.2.21 ?

#### SOLUTION

Invalid certificates aren't working anymore for authentication since version 3.2.21 and not 4.0 as specified in the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/

Regenerate certificates and removing ssl.allowInvalidCertificates fixed the problem.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/ says: Starting in MongoDB 4.0, if you specify --sslAllowInvalidCertificates or net.ssl.allowInvalidCertificates: true (or in MongoDB 4.2, the alias --tlsAllowInvalidateCertificates or net.tls.allowInvalidCertificates: true) when using x.509 authentication, an invalid certificate is only sufficient to establish a TLS/SSL connection but is insufficient for authentication.. Ensure your certs are valid.

Comment: the problem cannot be this one, as you say "Starting in mongodb 4.0"

Comment: Unless the change was backported to 3.2.21.

Comment: Yeah it was that, i regenerate all the certificates and it seems to works, thanks. 
Awesome documentation... :D